# How To Scroll gridview FocusedRowHandle SelectRow in devexpress

Tags: c#, gridview, scroll, devexpress, scrollbar

Hello I want to scroll my scrollbar to selected row

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZDYJ.png)

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far as formatted code text and not as image. Please read [ask] and try to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the [FocusedRowHandle](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.FocusedRowHandle) property should make this row visible. You can also try the following APIs:

- [GridView.MakeRowVisible()](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.MakeRowVisible.overloads)
- [GridView.TopRowIndex](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.TopRowIndex)

Refer to the following topic for more information on scrolling in GridView: [Scrolling](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114739/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/scrolling).